# Contrast detection implementation for blur detection in microscopic image

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision

I am currently doing a project where I have to detect if the the microscopic images given are blurry. I tried canny edge detection but they seem to perform not so good in detecting blur. I realised that I should rather look exactly for blur image detection. I found that modern cameras use contrast detection but I don't know how to implement it. Any ideas or resources to get it implemented. Any other approach which might help would also be great.

Thanks